# Convert OpenCV triangulatePoints output for use in perspectiveTransform using Python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

The output from cv2.triangulatePoints is specified as a 4xN array of reconstructed points in homogeneous coordinates.

I want to use this output as the src array input into cv2.perspectiveTransform. The src is specified to be a two-channel or three-channel floating-point array.

What would be the correct method to manipulate the triangulatePoints output array so it will fit into perspectiveTransform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me to figure it out:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/252/cv2perspectivetransform-with-python/

Here is how I implemented it:

```
    Tpoints1 = cv2.triangulatePoints(P_1, P_2, normRshp1, normRshp2)         
    #Grab the first three columns from the results to make a 3-N array
    Tpt1 = np.array([Tpoints1[0],Tpoints1[1],Tpoints1[2]])
    #Reshape to make a N-3 array
    Tpt1 = Tpt1.reshape(-1,3)
    #Make an array from the array resulting in [1,N,3]
    Tpt1 = np.array([Tpt1])
    #Reshape camera matrix to a 4x4 for input into perspectiveTransform 
    #we'll just add zeros and a one to the last row.
    # from the TestTriangualtion function @, 
    #https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/blob/master/Chapter4_StructureFromMotion/FindCameraMatrices.cpp
    P_24x4 = resize(P_2,(4,4))
    P_24x4[3,0] = 0
    P_24x4[3,1] = 0
    P_24x4[3,2] = 0
    P_24x4[3,3] = 1 
    Tpoints1_projected = cv2.perspectiveTransform(Tpt1, P_24x4)
```